# Manipulating text with symbols in PowerPoint using VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to use VBA to manipulate text in a PowerPoint.

I have formatted text in a frame with greek symbols, superscript and subscript. 
I want to divide that text into two frames.
For example I use something like this:

```
Dim frame1Text As String
Dim frame2Text As String
Set frame1 = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).TextFrame
Set frame2 = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(2).TextFrame
frame1Text = frame1.TextRange.Text
frame2Text = Right(frame1Text, Len(frame1Text) - 10)
frame1Text = Left(frame1Text, Len(frame1Text) - Len(frame2Text))
frame1.TextRange.Text = frame1Text
frame2.TextRange.Text = frame2Text
```

As a result there are symbols and formatting lost. Is there any way to make it better?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18062066/how-to-modify-text-in-powerpoint-via-excel-vba-without-changing-style?rq=1) may help.

Comment: Thank you, this is about change and replace. But how can I duplicate Slides(1).Shapes(1).TextFrame into Slides(1).Shapes(2).TextFrame.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, I would duplicate the shape and then delete what you don't want in the text. That way all formatting will be retained, character-by-character. Something along the lines of this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyText()
  Dim oShp1 As Shape
  Dim oShp2 As Shape

  Set oShp1 = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1)
  oShp1.Copy
  ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Shapes.Paste

  Set oShp2 = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.Count)

  With oShp1.TextFrame.TextRange
    .Text = Left(.Text, 10)
  End With

  With oShp2.TextFrame.TextRange
    .Text = Right(.Text, Len(.Text) - Len(oShp1.TextFrame.TextRange.Text))
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks JamieG for an advice.
Unfortunately
`.Text = Left(.Text, 10)` is not good enough. In that way I'm losing text formatting.
But it is OK when instead of Left (Right) I use `Characters(Start, Length).Delete`
The next disadvantage of this resolution is problem with the autosize of the TextFrame.
`oShp1.TextFrame.AutoSize = ppAutoSizeShapeToFitText`
works as I execute code step-by-step, but doesn't work at run-time - frames are very big.
IMHO because the copy-paste is very slow.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to post my code with the .Delete method too! Regarding the ppAutoSizeShapeToFitText you need to make sure you apply that last (after text is changed) if I recall correctly.

Comment: It's funny, ppAutoSizeShapeToFitText works correctly at run-time with PowerPoint 2013. Problems are with PowerPoint 2003.