# How to create font object vba

Tags: vba, powerpoint

So I guess this is pretty simple but im not sure how to create a Font object, or any object :( . I'm trying to copy the font of a word and apply it to another for another project but whenever I try to create a new Font object  I get errors (I can't just reference  the original object as it changes before the Font gets transferred to the other word). I'm really new to vba so this may be a stupid quiestion but I tried everything I've seen online and had no luck.
Here is what I tried next to the errors I get:

```
Sub helo()
-----------------------------

  Dim uno As Font

  Set uno = New Font
 'Invalid use of New Keyword
-----------------------------

Dim uno As Font

  Set uno = New Font1
'User-Defined type not defined
-----------------------------
Dim uno As PowerPoint.Font

  Set uno = New Font1
'User-Defined type not defined
-----------------------------
Dim uno As New Font

 'Invalid use of New Keyword
-----------------------------

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for any help, and please forgive me if this is a stupid question, I'm quite new.

Code for the project, I got it functional but it still loses all the format except for Bold and Underline. Some of it is copied from code I found online and some I wrote on my own. (it's really messy, sorry)

```
Sub Traductorpuntosycomas()
Dim regX As Object
Dim osld As Slide
Dim oshp As Shape
Dim intSlide As Integer
Dim strInput As String
Dim b_found As Boolean
Dim iRow As Integer
Dim iCol As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim strInput2() As String
Dim Bold(1000) As Integer
Dim Under(1000) As Integer
 

For i = 0 To 999

Bold(i) = 0
Under(i) = 0

Next i



Set regX = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")


For Each osld In ActivePresentation.Slides


For Each oshp In osld.Shapes

'TABLAS TABLAS TABLAS TABLAS TABLAS TABLAS TABLAS TABLAS TABLAS TABLAS TABLAS TABLAS'

If oshp.HasTable Then


For iRow = 1 To oshp.Table.Rows.Count


For iCol = 1 To oshp.Table.Columns.Count

'111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111'


With regX


.Global = True
.Pattern = "(\d)\.(\d)"


End With


strInput = oshp.Table.Cell(iRow, iCol).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text


strInput2 = Split(strInput, " ")

'BOLD UNDER BOLD UNDER BOLD UNDER BOLD UNDER BOLD UNDER BOLD UNDER BOLD UNDER BOLD UNDER BOLD UNDER'

For i = LBound(strInput2) To 2 * UBound(strInput2)

If oshp.Table.Cell(iRow, iCol).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Words(i + 1).Font.Bold = False Then
Bold(i) = 0
Else
Bold(i) = 1
End If
If oshp.Table.Cell(iRow, iCol).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Words(i + 1).Font.Underline = False Then
Under(i) = 0
Else
Under(i) = 1
End If

'INDENTATIONS INDENTATIONS INDENTATIONS INDENTATIONS INDENTATIONS INDENTATIONS INDENTATIONS INDENTATIONS '



Next i

For i = LBound(strInput2) To UBound(strInput2)

b_found = regX.Test(strInput2(i))


If b_found = True Then


strInput2(i) = regX.Replace(strInput2(i), "$1¬$2")


End If

Next i

strInput = Join(strInput2, " ")

oshp.Table.Cell(iRow, iCol).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = strInput

'222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222'

With regX


.Global = True
.Pattern = "(\d)\,(\d)"


End With


strInput = oshp.Table.Cell(iRow, iCol).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text


strInput2 = Split(strInput, " ")

'FOR'

For i = LBound(strInput2) To UBound(strInput2)


b_found = regX.Test(strInput2(i))


If b_found = True Then


strInput2(i) = regX.Replace(strInput2(i), "$1.$2")

End If

Next i

strInput = Join(strInput2, " ")

oshp.Table.Cell(iRow, iCol).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = strInput

'3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333'

With regX


.Global = True
.Pattern = "(\d)\¬(\d)"


End With


strInput = oshp.Table.Cell(iRow, iCol).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text


strInput2 = Split(strInput, " ")

'FOR'

For i = LBound(strInput2) To UBound(strInput2)


b_found = regX.Test(strInput2(i))


If b_found = True Then


strInput2(i) = regX.Replace(strInput2(i), "$1,$2")


End If

Next i

strInput = Join(strInput2, " ")

oshp.Table.Cell(iRow, iCol).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = strInput

'VUELTA AL FORMATO ORIGINAL'

For i = LBound(strInput2) To 2 * UBound(strInput2)

If Bold(i) = 1 Then
oshp.Table.Cell(iRow, iCol).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Words(i + 1).Font.Bold = True
Else
oshp.Table.Cell(iRow, iCol).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Words(i + 1).Font.Bold = False
End If
If Under(i) = 1 Then
oshp.Table.Cell(iRow, iCol).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Words(i + 1).Font.Underline = True
Else
oshp.Table.Cell(iRow, iCol).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Words(i + 1).Font.Underline = False
End If

Next i

'VUELTA AL FORMATO ORIGINAL'


Next iCol


Next iRow


'FINAL TABLAS FINAL TABLAS FINAL TABLAS FINAL TABLAS FINAL TABLAS FINAL TABLAS'

Else


If oshp.HasTextFrame Then


If oshp.TextFrame.HasText Then

With regX


.Global = True
.Pattern = "(\d)\.(\d)"


End With

 
strInput = oshp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text


strInput2 = Split(strInput, " ")



For i = LBound(strInput2) To 2 * UBound(strInput2)
'BOLD UNDER BOLD UNDER BOLD UNDER V BOLD UNDER BOLD UNDER BOLD UNDER BOLD UNDER'

If oshp.TextFrame.TextRange.Words(i).Font.Bold = False Then
Bold(i) = 0
Else
Bold(i) = 1
End If
If oshp.TextFrame.TextRange.Words(i).Font.Underline = False Then
Under(i) = 0
Else
Under(i) = 1
End If
Next i
For i = LBound(strInput2) To UBound(strInput2)
b_found = regX.Test(strInput2(i))


If b_found = True Then


strInput2(i) = regX.Replace(strInput2(i), "$1¬$2")




'oshp.TextFrame.TextRange.Words(i) = strInput2(i)


End If

Next i

strInput = Join(strInput2, " ")

oshp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = strInput


'1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111'

With regX


.Global = True
.Pattern = "(\d)\,(\d)"


End With

 
strInput = oshp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text


strInput2 = Split(strInput, " ")



For i = LBound(strInput2) To UBound(strInput2)


b_found = regX.Test(strInput2(i))


If b_found = True Then


strInput2(i) = regX.Replace(strInput2(i), "$1.$2")


'oshp.TextFrame.TextRange.Words(i) = strInput2(i)




End If

Next i

strInput = Join(strInput2, " ")

oshp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = strInput



'2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222'


With regX


.Global = True
.Pattern = "(\d)\¬(\d)"


End With

 
strInput = oshp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text


strInput2 = Split(strInput, " ")



For i = LBound(strInput2) To UBound(strInput2)


b_found = regX.Test(strInput2(i))


If b_found = True Then


strInput2(i) = regX.Replace(strInput2(i), "$1,$2")


'oshp.TextFrame.TextRange.Words(i) = strInput2(i)

End If


Next i

strInput = Join(strInput2, " ")

oshp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = strInput


'333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333'


'VUELTA AL FORMATO ORIGINAL'

For i = LBound(strInput2) To 2 * UBound(strInput2)

If Bold(i) = 1 Then
oshp.TextFrame.TextRange.Words(i).Font.Bold = True
Else
oshp.TextFrame.TextRange.Words(i).Font.Bold = False
End If
If Under(i) = 1 Then
oshp.TextFrame.TextRange.Words(i).Font.Underline = True
Else
oshp.TextFrame.TextRange.Words(i).Font.Underline = False
End If

Next i

'VUELTA AL FORMATO ORIGINAL'


End If


End If


End If



Next oshp


Next osld

Set regX = Nothing





End Sub
```

Comment: `Font` is only a property of an existing object - you cannot create a `Font` from scratch....   If you want to copy the format from one piece of text to another you'd need to loop over the properties one-by-one (bold, italic, underline, color, etc) and copy them to the destination text.  Similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47805916/save-all-information-from-a-range-and-restore-it-later/47808603#47808603

Comment: The thing is i need a way to store the properties, as the font of the word changes before I can copy them to the destination text. The reason for this is that the word I am transfering these properties is the same word I get them from, only after the text it belongs to gets converted into a string and goes though some code, which for some reason sets the same font for the whole text. Do you happen to have any ideas of how to get around this?

Comment: To change text without clearing its formatting you'd typically use the `Characters` property: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.textrange.characters and for example - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18062066/how-to-modify-text-in-powerpoint-via-excel-vba-without-changing-style

Comment: The macro I am creating looks for numers and changes their decimal separators from 1.000,2 to 1,000.2 and viceversa (switching the european decimal separators to english decimal separators and the ones in english to european). For this I used regexp (I think that's what ist's called) and looked for the pattern (\d)\.(\d), the same with commas, and swapped them though an in between step. Do you think there would be a way to do that with the characters property, as it works with strings (I think)?

Comment: Yes you should be able to do that as long as you know the positions of the characters you want to swap out.   If you could post your current code it would be easier to offer a fix.

Comment: To be clear what I'm trying to do is sweep though a shape's text, store the font values for every word, run it though my code (which messes up the fonts) amd then apply back the old font. I kinda managed to do this for bold and underline as those are true or false, so I just created a 2 arrays and wrote either 1's for bold/underline or 0's for not bold/underline for every word (maybe a boolean array would have been better but i have never used them), and it worked, but the rest of the font (font(arial,...) ,indentations, bullets,...) are not just true/false so I don't know how to do it.

Comment: ok I'll edit it and post the code, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example based on your posted code.

I'm not 100% sure on the regex pattern so you might need to tweak that...

```vb
Sub Traductorpuntosycomas()
    
    Dim osld As Slide
    Dim oshp As Shape
    Dim iRow As Integer
    Dim iCol As Integer
    
    For Each osld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each oshp In osld.Shapes
            If oshp.HasTable Then
                For iRow = 1 To oshp.Table.Rows.Count
                    For iCol = 1 To oshp.Table.Columns.Count
                        FixNumbers oshp.Table.Cell(iRow, iCol).Shape.TextFrame
                    Next iCol
                Next iRow
            End If
        Next oshp
    Next osld
End Sub

'check a textframe object and replace any numbers with their re-formatted form
Sub FixNumbers(tf As TextFrame)
    Dim regX As Object, matches, match, pos1 As Long, pos2 As Long, txt
    
    If Not tf.HasText Then Exit Sub 'nothing to process
    txt = tf.TextRange.Text
    Set regX = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With regX
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "\d+\.?\d+,?\d?" 'digits with optional `.` and `,`
    End With
    Set matches = regX.Execute(txt)
    For Each match In matches
        pos1 = InStr(match.Value, ".") 'find .
        pos2 = InStr(match.Value, ",") 'find ,
        'swap out without affecting formatting...
        If pos1 > 0 Then tf.TextRange.Characters(match.firstindex + pos1, 1) = ","
        If pos2 > 0 Then tf.TextRange.Characters(match.firstindex + pos2, 1) = "."
    Next match
End Sub
```

Comment: I can't possibly thank you enough for taking your time to make this, I was really stuck and had no idea how to make it work. Your code  works great and changing the pattern shouldn't be much trouble. Again thanks a lot for your time and have a great day :)

Comment: No problem - good to hear it works for you.